# ClassNotFoundException on class from jar that I can successfully load other classes from

Tags: java, ruby, classloader

**Background:**
I'm trying to start an embedded Tomcat server in a Java class, launched via JRuby from a Ruby script.  This means that all of the jars I use need to be loaded from the ruby script.

In the ruby script I have:

```
require 'java'
load 'servlet-api-2.5.jar'
...
com.mycompany.RunWebApplicationTomcat.main(nil)
//com.mycompany.RunWebApplicationJetty.main(nil)  //Commented out for Tomcat Test
```

And the Java class follows:

```
   public class RunWebApplicationTomcat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          try {
              Class.forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet");
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
              System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          }

          DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet =  new DispatcherServlet();
              ....
        }
   }
```

**Problem:**
When I run the script, I get no exception on the Class.forName test, but I get a *ClassNotFoundException on javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet* when the DispatcherServlet initialization is attempted.  (The DispatcherServlet is the spring servlet, but I've tried other servlet implementations and run into the same exception)

**Why I'm 99.9% sure the servlet-api.jar is in the classpath:**
Where this gets really strange is I have successfully created an Embedded Jetty server using this same pattern.  That server does not require the HttpServlet class.  It however does make use of the HttpServletRequest/Response classes, which are in the same servlet-api.jar, and it works perfectly.

**Questions:**
1.  Does anyone have an idea how one particular class in a jar that is loaded into the classpath is not able to be found?
2.  Is there some java security mechanism that can prevent a class from being instantiated? (The JRuby executable is a custom, proprietary, black-box so I'm not sure what might be happening in there)
3.  Are there any other tests I might perform that could shed some light on the problem?

**Stacktrace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `ClassNotFoundException` can be caused by a number of things, including the following:

- The class in question is not there.
- The class is there, but some other class / interface / annotation /enum that it depends on is not there.
- Your class depends on some other class that *previously* failed in class initialization.

The evidence seems to contradict all of these.  (According to the javadoc, `Class.forName(String)` triggers class initialization.)  However, the stack trace would provide more evidence.

---

Where could be something tricky going on here with classloaders; i.e. the DispatcherServlet class was previously loaded with a different class loader to the "current" one that `forName` is using.

You should also consider the possibility that `forName` is throwing a different `Exception` (or `Error`) that you are not testing for in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat supplies its own version of the servlet-api.jar. Differences in version might lead to missing classes.

From [Tomcat 7.0 Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

> Last, any JAR file that contains Servlet API classes will be explicitly ignored by the classloader — Do not include such JARs in your web application.